# I alt tabbed out of Skyrim and there's no way to tab back in

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After spending an hour in character creation I needed to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. I then tried to tab back in as usual, and it just goes to a black screen. Tabbing again does nothing. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can install mods that fix this issue, if you are willing to.

One tweak-  (I use this personally)
http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/40706/?

Even if you created your character yet again, you must install this mod, in order not to lose out on your progress in the future.

This will fix all window problems related to Skyrim. Hope this helps!